# php insert statement error

Tags: mysql, php

i had a query in mysql for just inserting some data
the query is

```
 $insert_query_pur  = "INSERT INTO `dbname`.`tblname` (`USER_NAME`,`PURCHASE_TYPE`,`PURCHASE_KEY`, `SUBSCRIPTION_ID`,`PURCHASE_DATE`,`NO_OF_ISSUE`,`MAGAZINE_ID`,`AppsCode`,`PROCESS_STATUS`,`User_price`,`Publisher_price`, `Publisher_price_inr`) VALUES ('$USER_NAME','$PURCHASE_TYPE','$PURCHASE_KEY','$SUBSCRIPTION_ID','$PURCHASE_DATE','$NO_OF_ISSUE','$MAGAZINE_ID','$AppsCode','$PROCESS_STATUS','$User_price','$Publisher_price','$Publisher_price_inr')";
```

but when i excecute this query i got an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /var/www/thewinkstore.com/magsonwink/modules/admin/support/classes/support_manage.class.php on line 685

i can't find what is the issue. please help me

Comment: Please post your codes 4 or 5 lines. it may be error with previous line

Comment: Query seems that ok, it could be in php. post your php code

Comment: Which part of the error message is hard for you to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put all in one line, in situations like these, you might loose the overview too fast.

The recommendation is that you make use of prepared statements for such insert queries so that you do not need to built the SQL string on your own. This is explained in the PHP manual.

For an interim improvement, you might want to first of all distribute the string over multiple lines:

```
$insert_query_pur  = "
INSERT INTO `dbname`.`tblname` 
    (
        `USER_NAME`,        `PURCHASE_TYPE`,   `PURCHASE_KEY`, 
        `SUBSCRIPTION_ID`,  `PURCHASE_DATE`,   `NO_OF_ISSUE`,
        `MAGAZINE_ID`,      `AppsCode`,        `PROCESS_STATUS`,
        `User_price`,       `Publisher_price`, `Publisher_price_inr`
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (
        '$USER_NAME',       '$PURCHASE_TYPE',   '$PURCHASE_KEY',
        '$SUBSCRIPTION_ID', '$PURCHASE_DATE',   '$NO_OF_ISSUE',
        '$MAGAZINE_ID',     '$AppsCode',        '$PROCESS_STATUS',
        '$User_price',      '$Publisher_price', '$Publisher_price_inr'
    )
";
```

Whitespace and indentation is your friend. I hope this helps even if it does not solve your concrete issue.